# Get category from wordpress rss [php]

Tags: php, wordpress, rss

Hi i need help to get all categories from rss.
This is ex. of my rss feed:

```
<item>
    <title>Coca-Cola</title>
    <link>https://www.tralaaa.com/coca-cola/</link>
    <comments></comments>
    <pubDate>Fri, 01 Dec 2017 11:36:40 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Admin]]></dc:creator>
    <category><![CDATA[cat1]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat2]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat3]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat4]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
</item>
```

I try with   `$cat =  $item->category(0);` but give me the error

> Call to undefined method SimpleXMLElement::category()

Comment: in that case give me only first category..

Answer (score 0):

You cant access category using `()` parenthesis, you need to use `[]`, like this:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement(
'<item>
    <title>Coca-Cola</title>
    <link>https://www.tralaaa.com/coca-cola/</link>
    <comments></comments>
    <pubDate>Fri, 01 Dec 2017 11:36:40 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator><![CDATA[Admin]]></dc:creator>
    <category><![CDATA[cat1]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat2]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat3]]></category>
    <category><![CDATA[cat4]]></category>
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <content:encoded><![CDATA[]]></content:encoded>
</item>');

$cat_name1 = $xml->category[0]->__toString();
$cat_name2 = $xml->category[1]->__toString();
$cat_name3 = $xml->category[2]->__toString();
$cat_name4 = $xml->category[3]->__toString();


echo "<pre>";
print_r($cat_name1);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cat_name2);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cat_name3);
echo "</pre>";
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cat_name4);
echo "</pre>";
```

this will output:

[image]

you can just:

```
$xml->category->__toString();
```

it will assume you want the first category.